# Use Variabel for 'ORDER BY ' Declartion in a FOR IN LOOP Oralce

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop

In ORACLE please.

Is it possible to have a variable in the 'ORDER BY' Statment?

So iam currenty creating a procedure in which I need to have a dynamic Order by.
Is there any way to do this ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1

vorder varchar(250);
...

vOrder := 'number';
FOR o IN (SELECT * FROM TABLENAME order by vOrder)
LOOP
-- Some stuff ---

END LOPP;
....
```

Comment: It would have to be a known column name, so a small(ish - hopefully) list of candidates; so have you tried using a case expression to translate the variable to an actual column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to really have a dynamic order by clause instead of just having a list of predefined options as suggested by Alex, would be to use a dynamic sql cursor.

```sql
TYPE curType IS REF CURSOR;
vCur curType;
vRec tablename%ROWTYPE;
vOrd VARCHAR2(250) := 'column';

BEGIN
   OPEN vCur FOR 'SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY '||vOrd';
   LOOP
      FETCH vCur INTO vRec;
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE vCur;
END;
/
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the tablename is also dynamic. So yes you’re right your solotion would work bur how do I make the tablename also dynamic ? Btw what do you mean with tablename%ROWTYPE ? So tablename obv is the name of my table but the rowtype part… like the rowtype of the column or what ? Like I said everything is dynamic. The table, so are the column and so are the rowtypes(int, varchar etc.)

Comment: I don’t understand your comment? Please accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Everything can be dynamic in the sql statement given that it is an arbitrary string.

Comment: %ROWTYPE allows you to define a record based in a table or view. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/ROWTYPE-attribute.html#GUID-4E0B9FE2-909D-444A-9B4A-E0243B7FCB99